# CSS and Javascript error in Internet Explorer only after assets are compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, asset-pipeline

So I am experiencing some CSS and Javascript errors in Internet Explorer for my Rails app. The thing is, everything works fine when assets are not compiled. However, once the assets are compiled into one application.css and one application.js, I start experiencing a lot issues (and only in Internet Explorer 7,8,9). Any idea why this would happen? I don't need a specific answer as to exact bug, but just general things to look out for to help me start searching for a fix.

Basically, why would compiling the assets cause a problem?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the IE 4095 selector limit bug: IE ignores everything after the 4095th selector in a css file.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161

you can test for this case here: http://marc.baffl.co.uk/browser_bugs/css-selector-limit/

Your single css files won't extend this amount (hopefully) but all css files combined - might.

If you're using jammit for your compression, you can split your compressed asset files by editing your assets.yml file:

```
stylesheets:
  common:
   file1.css
   file2.css
  other:
   file3.css
   file4.css
```

jammit will then split your files into common.css and other.css
don't forget calling these files in your view:

```
   <%= include_stylesheets :common, :media => 'all' -%>
   <%= include_stylesheets :other, :media => 'all' -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any IE specific stylesheets or java code in your layouts..

like

```
<!--[if IE ] --><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie' %><!-- [endif]-->
```

if so then you'd need to add something like this

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(ie.css)
```

or it could be a compression issue
    config.assets.compress == false

or if you're using any 3rd party CSS stuff like css3pie etc

Comment: Hm no that doesn't help. The thing that is baffling me is why it works fine when assets are not compiled. But then it breaks when they are compiled. I don't have any ie.css file.